# place all scripts in 1 .js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a collection of about 10 scripts that are currently sitting in the head of my index.php. I would like to take these out and place them all into 1 .js file. I would then like to call this 1 .js file from index.php.

I have attempted to do this without success. Is there a line of code I need to place in the top of my new .js file to make all the scripts start running?

Please excuse my ignorance and thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: Should there be a certain order to the scripts when they are compiled into one JS file? Check your developer console for JS errors.

Comment: What does "without success" mean? Your first paragraph sets out a pretty straightforward process.

Comment: what have you 'tried'? your code in a jsfiddle/pastebin?

Comment: You should not have js files in the head -- put them at the end of your html that will give you a big performance gain.

Comment: </body>
</html>
(put js files here?) @Hogan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is nothing to add. But you also dont need the script tags. In the js file

The scripts become one happy family. .

Comment: Ahh. Thats all I need to do. Its working just fine now. Thanks heaps for your help.